# Expectation of balls in a jar

Tags: probability, distributions, expected-value

Trying to solve this question:

A jar contains 10 balls numbered 1,2,3,...,10. We draw 15 balls from the jar, one after the other, with replacement. Let N denote the number of distinct numbers drawn.

For example, if all numbers are drawn except 1 and 2, then N = 8.

Find the expected value of N.

I've tried to solve it by calculating the summation of this:

(x)(10Cx)(x/10)^15

Where x goes from 1 till 10. I got 45.855 but it's wrong apparently.

Comment: This is a part of a solution to the [Coupon collector's problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=coupon+collector).  Solutions to *generalizations* of your question, which can be specialized to your situation just by plugging in numbers, appear in https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/320152, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/121205. Your problem can also be easily solved by exploiting the results at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/90515 and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/487741.

Comment: In R: `mean(replicate(10^6, length(unique(sample(1:10, 15, repl=T)))))` returns $7.94$ with 95% margin of simulation error $\pm 0.001.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $E_i$ be the event that the number $i$ has been seen at least once in the drawn sequence of the numbers of balls where $i=1,\dots,10$, and $1_{E_i}$ be the indicator random variable of the event $E_i$.
Now, Let $N$ denote the number of distinct numbers drawn.
We have $N= \sum_ {i=1}^{10} 1_{E_i}$
and thus the expected value of $N$,
\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E} \left( N \right)
& = \sum_ {i=1}^{10} \mathbb{E} \left( 1_{E_i} \right)\\
& = \sum_ {i=1}^{10} \mathbb{P} \left( {E_i} \right)\\
& = \sum_ {i=1}^{10}  \left(1- \mathbb{P} \left( {E_i}^c \right)\right)\\
& = \sum_ {i=1}^{10}  \left(1-  \left( \frac{9}{10} \right)^{15} \right) \\
& = 10 \times \left(1-  \left( \frac{9}{10} \right)^{15} \right) \\
& \approx  7.941
\end{align*}